# Getting random points from large FeatureCollection without exceeding user memory limit of Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do you select random points from a large FeatureCollection without exceeding the user memory limit?

```
var bigData = ee.FeatureCollection('GLIMS/current');
var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(bigData, 100);
print(randomPoints.size()) // Error: User memory limit exceeded
```

This works on smaller FeatureCollections:

```
var smallData = bigData.filter(ee.Filter.eq('geog_area','Iceland'))
var smallRandomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(smallData, 100);
print(smallRandomPoints.size()) // 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'bigData' FC GLIMS contains over half a million features, each with a complex geometry. Using the entire collection as a single geometry causes the out-of-memory error.

If you want to choose 100 random points on glaciers, first choose 100 random glaciers:

```
var randomGlaciers = bigData
  .randomColumn()
  .sort('random')
  .limit(100)
```

Now make a random point on each glacier

```
print('100 random glacier points', randomGlaciers.map(function(f){
  f = ee.Feature(f);
  // make a random point within the glacier geometry
  var random = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(f.geometry(100), 1)
  return ee.Feature(random.first().geometry(100)) // or set the point as property of each feature if desired
}))
```